# ¿como puedo hacer este programa? me enrede

Tags: c#

a) Crear una clase llamada persona con las siguientes propiedades:
o   Nombre
o   Apellido
o   Edad (validar que sea correcta)
b) Constructores para inicializar las 3 propiedades.
c) Métodos:
o   Saludar() : muestra el nombre y apellido de la persona.
o   ToString() : imprime todas sus propiedades
d) En la clase Program instanciar dos objetos de tipo persona y llamar a su método saludar.

Comment: ¿Qué llevas hecho?, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: tengo echo ls primera clase con los nombre que pide hay pero lo demas me enrreda ayuda plz :(